# jQuery UI Color Picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, documentation, color-picker

I have heard that jQuery UI includes a Color Picker but could find little documentation regarding it.

Does it exist?

Any decent documentation on how to implement it?

I found this: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Colorpicker

But using:

```
$("#colorpicker").colorpicker();
```

does not work, with Firebug telling me `.colorpicker();` is not a method!

It seems to work fine, unless I put it in a dialog UI where it then decides to break.

Comment: You can find the code here: http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/ui/colorpicker?rev=5143

but looks like it's not really available from their site any more, might be worth using the one Shin recommended in the answers below, looked quite good!

Comment: I searched long and high for a good user friendly one that was just the colours and nothing else: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/02/jquery-minicolors-a-color-selector-for-input-controls/

Comment: I like that one, Chud. Clean and simple.

Comment: If anybody is reading this in 2017, HTML5 color input type is pretty much fully supported now (apart from IE) https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can find some demos and plugins here.

http://jqueryui.pbworks.com/ColorPicker

Comment: Yup, I shall try this tommorow. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps I am very late, but as of now there's another way to use it using the jquery ui [slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#colorpicker).

Here's how its shown in the jquery ui docs:

```js
function hexFromRGB(r, g, b) {
    var hex = [
      r.toString( 16 ),
      g.toString( 16 ),
      b.toString( 16 )
    ];
    $.each( hex, function( nr, val ) {
      if ( val.length === 1 ) {
        hex[ nr ] = "0" + val;
      }
    });
    return hex.join( "" ).toUpperCase();
  }
  function refreshSwatch() {
    var red = $( "#red" ).slider( "value" ),
      green = $( "#green" ).slider( "value" ),
      blue = $( "#blue" ).slider( "value" ),
      hex = hexFromRGB( red, green, blue );
    $( "#swatch" ).css( "background-color", "#" + hex );
  }
  $(function() {
    $( "#red, #green, #blue" ).slider({
      orientation: "horizontal",
      range: "min",
      max: 255,
      value: 127,
      slide: refreshSwatch,
      change: refreshSwatch
    });
    $( "#red" ).slider( "value", 255 );
    $( "#green" ).slider( "value", 140 );
    $( "#blue" ).slider( "value", 60 );
  });
```

```css
#red, #green, #blue {
float: left;
clear: left;
width: 300px;
margin: 15px;
}
#swatch {
width: 120px;
height: 100px;
margin-top: 18px;
margin-left: 350px;
background-image: none;
}
#red .ui-slider-range { background: #ef2929; }
#red .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #ef2929; }
#green .ui-slider-range { background: #8ae234; }
#green .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #8ae234; }
#blue .ui-slider-range { background: #729fcf; }
#blue .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #729fcf; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="padding:4px;">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span>
  Simple Colorpicker
</p>
 
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
 
<div id="swatch" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have jQuery UI base and the color picker widget included on your page (as well as a copy of jQuery 1.3):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/latest/themes/flora/flora.all.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Flora (Default)">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/latest/ui/ui.core.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/latest/ui/ui.colorpicker.js"></script>
```

If you have those included, try posting your source so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem (is not a method) with jQuery when working on autocomplete. It appeared the code was executed before the autocomplete.js was loaded. So make sure the ui.colorpicker.js is loaded before calling colorpicker.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are trying to access the plugin before it's loaded. You should try making a call to it when the DOM is loaded by surrounding it with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#colorpicker").colorpicker();
}
```