# color picker in iphone

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari

I used below code of color picker,

```
<input type="color" value="#000000" onChange="changeTextColor()">
```

This is showing as a textbox with color hex value in Safari browsers in iPhone. No color palette is showing on clicking it. Is there any alternative that should work in all mobile browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input), `<input type="color">` is not supported in Mobile Safari. If you want to go for a cross-browser solution, there are multiple solutions available. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971152/jquery-ui-color-picker) for other libraries.